# How to make a UIImageView take up a fixed percent of the screen regardless of device?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, view

Assume I have one big UIImageView that is set to a vector, and I want this ImageView to take up 90% of the screens width while maintaining it's aspect ratio, regardless of device, since it is a vector, resizing is not an issue. Height does not matter since I need it to just maintain it's aspect ratio, so long as it is 90% of the width of the screen. How can I do this in UIBuilder?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how to make an image width 90% of its superview:

1. Add the `UIImageView` to the Storyboard.
2. <kbd>control</kbd>-drag from the imageView to the background view.
3. Select *Equal Widths* from the pop-up.
4. Change the `multiplier` for the constraint to `0.9`.
5. To set up the aspect ratio, <kbd>control</kbd>-drag from the `UIImageView` to itself and select *Aspect Ratio* from the pop-up.  Set the `multiplier` value of the resulting constraint to the desired value.  You can use a ratio such as `3:4` or a floating point value such as `0.75`.
6. In the *Attributes Inspector* set the *Content Mode* of the `UIImageView` to *Scale To Fill*, *Aspect Fit*, or *Aspect Fill* so that the `UIImage` fills the `UIImageView`.

Comment: Thanks! I found another solution similar to this too, perhaps you could explain why it's inferior to your steps. 1) Follow your steps up until step 4 2) Then instead of control-dragging, click your imageView and select 'aspect-fill' in View, mode. They seem to have an identical effect.

Comment: My method sets up a constraint which sets up the height of the UIImageView.  If you don't set the height of the imageView, you could get unpredictable results.  You should really do both.  Set the aspect ratio constraint so that Auto Layout knows how tall to make the UIImageView, and then set *aspect fit* or *aspect fill* so that the UIImage fills the space specified by the UImageView.

Comment: Where you might notice a difference between my method and the other is if you had a label that was `8` points below the image, my method would properly size the `UIImageView` to make that possible.

Comment: After doing some more testing, this only works if the imageView is not bordering any other view. When bordering another view (like the top of the screen), the results go back to exactly what they were before (variable sizes on different devices).

Comment: IMPORTANT: Disregard my last statement, it was my fault, I was not Control-dragging into the view ITSELF when clicking aspect ratio. Clicking into itself works fully. Thanks!